Какие типы данных в C# являются неизменяемыми?
Как известно, в C# тип string является неизменяемым. В том смысле, что, если, например, к объекту типа string прибавить другой объект типа string, то в куче создастся новый объект типа string, а все старые объекты уничтожатся сборщиком мусора.
Какие ещё типы данных в C# имеют аналогичное свойство?

Examples of Immutable Types in .Net

@Grundy вот со структурами он загнул там, числовые примитивы очень даже мутабельные, и в куче они не живут, они вообще в оперативе могут не жить в целом.

@aepot, тут надо сначала определиться что считать мутабельными
